# Android - Scale Image to status bar of the phone

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Simply, I have a linear layout that separates the screen to 2 pieces from middle and in the first piece I have a constraint layout that contains mountain.png .Because of i set NoActionBar and white for statusBarColor in Themes.xml, as a result above the image there is area that seems white.So I want to remove the white area and scale the image through status bar of the phone.

I tried to remove status bar, it didn't work.
I tried to add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" attribute to .XML file and it didn't work too.

My .xml file

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.sign_in.telephone.PhoneNumberFragment"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/mountain">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/baslaText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="38sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Başlayın" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/baslaText"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Taşımaya başlamak için kaydolun, ilk \n olarak telefon numaranızı girin"
                />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="14dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/telephoneNumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="30dp"
                    android:text="Telefon numaranızı giriniz"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/telephoneText"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/telephoneNumber"
                    android:text="Taşımaya başlamak için kaydolun, ilk \n olarak telefon numaranızı girin"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/telephoneTag"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:text="Telefon Numarası"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/telephoneText" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/telephoneNumberInput"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/telephoneTag"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    >
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/telephoneNumberEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:hint="+.. ... ... .. .."
                        android:maxLength="12"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/purple_500"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_500"
                    android:text="Başlayın"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/telephoneNumberInput" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My themes.xml file.

```
   <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.UI" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

This code piece did the job I desired.

Answer (score 0):

write this on your activity onCreate:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work in the way I wanted. Your code removes the statusBar and it shows black area above the image but I want to scale my image throughout the statusBar.